# C# Events and EventHandler

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

I just got started with C# and I am currently learning about Events and Delegates. I understand (hopefully) that the EventHandler is what is going to be called when the event occurs. My question is on the following code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Timer foo = new Timer();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foo.Tick += new EventHandler(Bar);
            foo.Interval = 1000;
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foo.Start();
        }

        private void Bar(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Tick!");
        }
    }
```

Which is correct and why?

```
foo.Tick += new EventHandler(Bar);                      
or                
foo.Tick += Bar;
```

They both seem to work the same. Although there are some similar questions around here I don't seem to get it. Sorry if the question is dumb I am really new to .NET.

Comment: There's no difference, actually "foo.Tick += Bar" is a syntactic sugar and equals to "foo.Tick += new EventHandler(Bar)"

Answer (score 0):

They are the same. `foo.Tick += Bar` is syntactic sugar for `foo.Tick += new EventHandler(Bar)`.